# Issue concurrent and contiguous job IDs

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I need to issue job IDs that are both concurrent and as contiguous as possible, ideally in a fairly seamless and lightweight manner. I'm using SQLAlchemy and Postgresql.

## Contiguous

I only want the issued ID to be considered taken if the job was successful and the ID persisted in the newly written DB row. This way there will be no gaps in the issued IDs in the DB. If the DB transaction fails during the job, I want that ID to be freed up for the next job. If the first ID to be issued is 1 and the first 5 jobs all fail, I want the 6th job attempt to be issued the ID 1, not 6.

## Concurrent

I could take `max(ID) + 1` for the next ID, but this doesn't work for concurrent requests, since all concurrent jobs will take the same number.

I understand that contiguousness is not guaranteed. If 5 jobs are launched simultaneously, each taking the IDs 1-5, and only #5 survives, I'll just have #5 persisted. That's OK. I have low concurrency and a large number of job failures and without attempting contiguity, I'd have gaping holes in the sequences. Requests are not often concurrent, so the likelihood of a gap is low. The result will be at most an occasional small gap.

## Ideas

1. I could write a service that issues IDs to concurrent jobs, but it would need a way to know if the client job has failed in order to free up the ID. It's also a single point of failure and too much additional engineering for this.
2. I was thinking of having each job put `max(ID) + 1` in a temporary table in the DB in such a way that other jobs could see the uncommitted change. If the transaction fails, the new ID also falls off with it. In this sense, all jobs would actually pick `max(ID of completed jobs, uncommitted IDs in the temp table) + 1`. If the new ID commits, I no longer need it anyway and can delete it from the temp table. It's an awkward pattern and not sure how I would do it.
3. I could do the above but commit the IDs in progress instead and delete them on successful job completion. The table would thus represent "in process" IDs. Without a way to delete those IDs for failed transactions though, I'd need some kind of periodic pruning to delete "abandoned" IDs based on age or some less than ideal heuristic.
4. I could do the above and include a PID in the table. A periodic process would delete rows where the PID is no longer valid, but that solution won't scale to a distributed setup and I'd prefer not to have a polling process active all the time for the system to function.
5. Or maybe use a DB session ID instead of PID? At least that's distributable and I could catch invalid DB sessions more quickly and easily? But my application may need admin privileges to check if DB session IDs are valid.
6. The ideal solution for me is #3 + if there were a way in SQLAlchemy to run some DB code only when a transaction fails. I assume all failures will appear as an exception in Python, so maybe some kind of global `except()` block, but it might get messy trying to separate DB transaction failures from other Python exceptions that I don't want to catch globally. It would be better if I could register some cleanup code with SQLAlchemy to run whenever a transaction fails, which would delete the issued ID.
7. Something similar but on the DB, like a trigger on transaction failure.
8. I could issue a UUID as the job number and upon successful transaction commit, map the UUID to `max(ID) + 1` at that point, but I'm not sure if it's concurrent and it would be tedious because the ID is stamped on a bunch of files created during the job, so I'd have to go around renaming everything on disk.
9. Leverage Postgresql Sequences somehow? But they don't seem to care about contiguity.

Is there any nifty approach to this? If not, I'm leaning towards #3 because of its simplicity.

Comment: You could use a SEQUENCE or IDENTITY for the primary key, which will be non-contiguous but unique. Insert the row with a null job_id, then if the commit is successful retrieve the newly-generated PK and do `UPDATE the_table SET job_id = (SELECT MAX(job_id) + 1 FROM the_table) WHERE pk_column = new_pk`

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson. The job id isn't the primary key in this case and there are multiple rows tagged with the job id. IIUC, Sequence numbers are not recycled if the transaction fails. I also need the job id during the transaction.

Comment: "there are multiple rows tagged with the job id" - so you're essentially using it like a foreign key. In that case the `job_id` should probably be in a separate (parent) table with a SEQUENCE/IDENTITY primary key and use that as the foreign key so the `job_id` is only written down in one place. TL;DR: For a database with multiple concurrent users, identifiers like `job_id` can be (a) contiguous, (b) available before committing, (c) unique. Pick two.

Comment: "you're essentially using it like a foreign key" - 
Not really, because it's just the job id. There are no foreign table columns associated with it. If I treated it like a FK, I'd still need to link to the FK multiple times, so I'm not sure what I'd be saving.

Comment: It's *like* a foreign key because it is an identifier that is repeated several times in a given column, like the foreign key in the child table of a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping there would be a SQLAlchemy or Postgres hook that would get called when a transaction ends nominally or abnormally, but the [after_transaction_end](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.after_transaction_end) event unfortunately doesn't fire if the application crashes.

The solution that worked for me was a variation of #6, but with a context manager instead of a global `finally()` block. The key insight was that Python calls `__exit__` reliably, both during nominal operation and after a crash, without having to catch exceptions globally. The only missing piece was when I force stop the Python debugger, but for this PyCharm can be configured to kill processes softly, which will call `__exit__`.

My solution is as follows:

1. Create an active jobs table with a PK/unique constraint on the job id
2. For the new job id, pick max(existing, active jobs)
3. Commit the new job id in the active jobs table. If two concurrent jobs had picked the same job id, insert will fail here for the second one because it would violate the unique constraint, thus ensuring concurrency
4. Make the data class a context manager, where `__exit__` deletes its job id from the active jobs table
5. Use the data class in a `with` clause
6. Configure PyCharm to kill processes softly so that a debugger kill will still clean up the active jobs table

I find this to be more elegant than exception handling and quite robust.